# routing traffic - iptables

Tags: debian, iptables, routing, squid

Im trying to route some traffic on my lan.

I have a squid3 server on 192.168.0.1:3128 and all web traffic is going through squid3. (Transparent via iptables)
And now I have a testing server up and running [havp](http://www.server-side.de/) on 192.168.0.24:3127

*Squid3 caches,
havp checks for malware and virus*

Is there a way to "cut" into traffic before it hits my squid server, and pass i through my havp server? havp is setup up to forward traffic back to 192.168.0.1:3128 (non ssl traffic)

This is the iptables syntax I have tried so far:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth3 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-destination 192.168.0.24:3127
```

And this one:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth3 --dst 192.168.0.24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3127
```

None of them are working. 192.168.0.24 is setup to accept traffic on port 3127.

If I manually connect to the havp server, It's working like a charm.

```
My browser -> havp -> squid3 -> internets
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Use `-I` instead of `-A`

`-A` appends the rule to the end, -I inserts it at the top. Since you've said it's already acting transparently, you must already have a rule to redirect the traffic to 3128. The first matching rule ends the checks, with your current attempts once the first (original) rule is matched, your second one never gets checked.

A better option is probably to setup havp as a parent proxy to squid.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. havp is already parent to squid. And havp takes care of the traffic from havp to squid again. But I have no way to send the traffic from 192.168.0.1 -> 192.168.0.24:3127 (havp)

Comment: [look her for diagram] (http://bildr.no/view/1389674)